# Showing status of a batch update operation using WebApi

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I need to know how to update UI with the status of a batch update operation. For example i am sending a request to **WebApi** to update multiple records (could be any number of records), now i want to show the status of each record to client side.

Please suggest me the best way of doing that. I am using **WebApi**, Angular. I am thinking about implementing **SignalR** that can update Client UI with respect to the status but is there an another way of doing that ??

Answer (score 0):

signalr may be overkill for what could be a simple polling request to your api.

It's a little ambiguous as to exactly what it is you are doing with your batch update operation, but since your looking to get status back I'm going to assume it's a long slow operation that your not waiting on a response for in the initial request.

Web api has REST principles baked into it from the start so I imagine your batch update operation is using a PUT with a set of objects that need to be updated. If so you could simply request those objects back from your api to check their state and see if the operation has updated them yet.

If your not doing a simple PUT on an entity and it's more like a POST to submit a batch operation you should persist the operation entity and return a reference to it in the initial call then subsequently poll for that operation by id to get its current status.

signalr might let it feel a little more realtime by immediately pushing completed events down to the client but it can also bring a lot more overhead for what you are trying to achieve